# Collapsable block for custom language in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to create a custom highlighter for notepad++. I know how to do most of it, but I cant figure out how to set up code blocks like loops so that they can be collapsed. Is this possible?

Edit: Looking into it further, I think it might be folder open/close. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Correct. In **User-Defined** window, go to tab **Folder&Default** and you have three sections there like:

- **Open** is the beginning of the collapsible section.
- **Middle** is useful for cases like IF - **ELSE** - ENDIF.
- **Close** is closing of the collapsible section.

One of three sections is for comments, other two are for your priamry language structures.